# Why Paste Event in jQuery fires on pre-paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I am trying to make textbox similar to the **Twitter**, for this I have written code for:

- Word Count
- Used Events Change, Keyup and Paste

`Keyup` and `Change` Events are working fine but paste event is little bit strange, when I paste something in textarea the word count doesn't change at that moment, after some debugging I found that **paste event fires up before pasting something on textbox**. I don't know how they handle this in Twitter.

Here is my code:
events:

```
'click #textboxId'  : 'submitQuestion'
'keyup #textboxId'  : 'wordCounter'
'change #textboxId' : 'wordCounter'
'paste #textboxId'  : 'wordCounter'

wordCounter: ->  
  #Code for Word Count#
```

Due to pre-paste nature of paste event the work count doesn't changes on that instance.

Your suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Comment: doesn't change event handle all these

Comment: @WebDeveloper No, change event doesn't update count on paste( instantly), we have to click out of textbox after pasting something.

Comment: @WebDeveloper - the problem is right mouse button or toolbar pasting. I was really surprised that `change` event was not catching this.

Comment: What language is that code in? It's not JavaScript (including jQuery) - unless you've deleted a bunch of curly braces and so forth...in which case it's no longer JavaScript. Anyway, if you get an "about to paste" event you could add a `setTimeout` hack to update the wordcount a few milliseconds later. But in general even if you get it working with whatever browser(s) you're testing on, some browsers don't let you handle the paste event at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn Its backbone.js and coffee-script. Ok, I will try setTimeout funtion. Thanks.

Comment: @WebDeveloper Its all there in my question, do you mean wordCount code?

Comment: oh it's coffeescript then i dont have any idea of it. Still i have a jquery code below try to convert it to coffee script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/urEhK/1

```
$('textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).val().length + ' characters');
});
```

That behavior was very weird. You would think that one of those events would catch this properly? I was surprised there weren't more answers to this via Google.

Comment: The change event is only triggered when you leave the field (tabbing or clicking out of it).

Comment: @mrtsherman - Thanks. I tried change event earlier and yes its weird that after pasting in textbox the count changed only when i click outside the box. Actually when it wasn't working so found somewhere that paste event can handle this, but result was same. Anyways I will try it again using Change and Keyup event. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
   function update()    
   {
       alert($textbox.val().length);
   }


    var $textbox = $('input');
    $textbox.bind('keyup change cut paste', function(){
        update(); //code to count or do something else
    });
    // And this line is to catch the browser paste event
    $textbox.bind('input paste',function(e){ setTimeout( update, 250); });
```

Comment: @WebDeveloper- Only syntax change difference is there in coffeescript nothing else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should now use on() instead of bind() [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on). 
It's also unnecessary to create a named function, you can just create a anonymous function.

```
$('#pasteElement').on('paste', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert($('#pasteElement').val());
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing that firstly get original data . then you can get the event paste  data and add them.

```
  $("#id").on("paste keypress ",function(event){
                // eg. you want to get last lenght
                 var length=$("#id").val().length;
                 if(event.type == "paste"){
                    //then you can get paste event data.=

length+=event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').length;
                }


            });`
```

Comment: the code is best for copy paste word limit event and limiting the limit of words .