# jQuery post-paste post-cut events

Tags: jquery, events, post

I know if I write `$("textarea").on("paste cut", function(e) {})`, then the event handler will be called whenever paste or cut actions are occurring but before the text has been pasted or cut, i.e., before the actions have been completed. But my question is how to make the handlers be called right after the actions have been completed? Thanks.

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simple-custom-afterpaste-event

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557995/why-paste-event-in-jquery-fires-on-pre-paste

Comment: @abhitalks 2nd one is good.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this satisfies ur requirement. Though its not cleanest solution and is kinda hack. Still you can try it

```
$("textarea").on('paste', function(e) {
         setTimeout(function() {
            //Your logic
        }, 100);//time in ms
});
```

Comment: It is hacky and same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2242485/1243867), I wouldn't prefer at the moment.